# Boto: upload to Amazon S3 OK, but upload to Google Cloud Storage: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, boto

I am using almost exact codes to upload files to Amazon S3 and Google Cloud Storage, respectively, using boto:

```
import boto

filename = 'abc.png'
filenameWithPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/' + filename
cloudFilename = 'uploads/' + filename

# Upload to Amazon S3
conn = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(AWS_BUCKET_NAME)
fpic = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket)
fpic.key = cloudFilename
fpic.set_contents_from_filename(filenameWithPath)

# Upload to Google Cloud Storage
conn = boto.connect_gs(gs_access_key_id=GS_ACCESS_KEY, gs_secret_access_key=GS_SECRET_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(GS_BUCKET_NAME)
fpic = boto.s3.key.Key(bucket)
fpic.key = cloudFilename
fpic.set_contents_from_filename(filenameWithPath)
```

The Amazon S3 part of code runs perfectly. However, the Google Cloud Storage part gives the error message `TypeError, 'str' does not support the buffer interface` at the statement `fpic.set_contents_from_filename(...)`.

What was the problem?

Comment: Where are you importing Key from?  Can you provide a stack trace for the TypeError?

Comment: I have re-edit the question: Key is imported from `boto.s3.key`. I have to put the Traceback in the answer area as follows.

Comment: By the way, in Amazon S3 I have to set CORS. But in Google Cloud Storage, I didn't find any place for doing that? Do I have to set CORS for Google Storage? If yes, how?

Comment: For CORS, see boto.gs.cors.Cors.  Can you also try with boto.gs.key.Key?

Comment: Yes! That's the problem: `boto.gs.key.Key`. Problem solved. Thanks a lot, Travis.